# snmpd timeout: No response from localhost

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I am running Centos 6.3 and attempting to use snmp v3 to query OID's on this server. Running Paessler's snmp tester 5.1.3 I get a no response from host. I have made sure that my iptables do not have any odd firewall settings. I can verify that snmpd is listening on port 161. I have also made sure that SELinux is fully disabled. I am able to install this on Centos 7.1 without any issue. I have done a tail on the messages in var/log/messages and can see incoming traffic for snmpd. I am stumped and have no idea why this will work on one version of this OS but not another. I wonder if anyone has any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: did you try checking traffic packets using tcpdump??

Comment: Actually this has been resolved now. I had to do some more digging and could not find a real issue. I did reboot the server (which shouldn't have affected snmpd) but after the reboot I was able to send snmpd requests to the server.

Comment: Probably, you may have figured out some bug in snmp itself, which might went away after restarting the system (including snmpd).